# How to find pair edge while building half-edge datastructure

Tags: data-structures, cg

I wrote my half-edge datastructure based on [this webpage](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml).

The mesh is loaded from a .obj, contained info for each vertex and what 3 vertices compose a face.
The only problem is: how do I know what's the pair edge for a specific edge?

Right now I record not only end vertex but also start vertex info in edge struct, 
compare O(N^2) to find out pair edge.
I think there is a better way but don't know how.